Why adding ReactPlayer not working when type:module
I am trying to include React-player component as below
<ReactPlayer
                url={current.video.Location}
                width="410px"
                height="240px"
                controls= {true}
                />

I have in package.json
"type":"module"
I get this error
Unhandled Runtime Error
Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object. Check the render method of `UpdateLessonForm`.

If I remove "type":"module",it loads fine
Is there any way, I can continue to use type:module and make it work

Hey, I am wondering whether you have already found an answer/solution to your problem? I am facing the same issue.
